# Distribute circles around a center circle

Tags: javascript, geometry, computational-geometry, famo.us

I'm trying to place six circles around a center circle.
Eeach of them has the same diameter so it should be possible to place them around the center without space between or overlaps.
I thinking to be close to the solution but there are small overlaps.
I can't find an answer how to get a perfect calculation.

**Thats my current result:**
[image: Current result]

**and this the way how I've calculated it:**

```
this.distribute = function () {

    var surfaceSize = this.surface.getAbsoluteSize(),
        i,
        x = 0,
        y = 0;

    // 7 CIRCLES 6 AFFECTED
    for (i = 0; i < this.config.length; i += 1) {
        var oBall = this.getBall(i);


        if (i > 0) {
            x = oBall.config.size.width * Math.sin(i);
            y = oBall.config.size.height * Math.cos(i);
        }

        oBall.node.setPosition(x, y, 0);
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you will like : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_chain ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just play with `60 deg === PI/3`:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/nk0ms9hb/

```
var circles = document.querySelectorAll('div.circles > div');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(circles, function (circle, index) {

    var angle = index * Math.PI / 3;

    circle.style.top = Math.sin(angle) + 'em';
    circle.style.left = Math.cos(angle) + 'em';
});
```

I'm using ems to ease the calculations like `2 * radius === 1em`