# Distribution of n-set of circles along optimal circumference

Tags: javascript, algorithm, d3.js, geometry, packing

Let's say, there is an arbitrary set of circles with different radiuses.

[image]

Have to distribute these circles in this way:

[image]

Pretty sure, that first of all need to find R, but don't know how to do it?

UPDATE: Theoretically, this problem could be solved by a simple "brute-force" by setting inner circle radius to smallest one and increasing it step by step while all circles would fit circumference.

But, that's a last resort, hope there is a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: So basically, you need to find the radius for a circle big enough to have all the other circles right?

Comment: Yes, they should be distributed along its circumference in a way shown on the second illustration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distribute circles around a center circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426255/distribute-circles-around-a-center-circle)

Comment: I have already an algorithm for one size circles, it's just a simple trigonometry since they form a regular n-polygon.

Looking for the solution for  different radiuses.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is a more elegant solution based on pure trigonometry.

Comment: did you read the wiki link in the comments for that question?

Comment: You mean Steiner Chain? Looked even before posting this question. SC is very limited and doesn't fit for any n-set with circles with arbitrary radiuses.

And, one more time, it's not a duplicate, cause if you have even circles, all you need is a line: innerCircleRadius = circleRadius / cos((n - 2) * PI / (n / 2); // n - 2, 2 could be less for gaps between circles.

Comment: What happens if there happens to be small enough circle(s) fitting inside the gaps between those circumferencing and the center one..?

Answer (score 1):

There is a general solution for this posted on StackExchange Mathematics: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407779/arranging-circles-around-a-circle

Regarding your idea of brute-force, we can improve that by using binary search on R instead.

Comment: As I have already mentioned, there should be a trigonometry solution.

Comment: @VVK exactly. And it's posted on StackExchange Mathematics :)